# Will running a computer program perpetually damage my computer?

Tags: script, sleep, javascript, node.js

I've written a Node.JS script for a Twitter bot that I made recently. It sends a tweet to the Twitter API at the top of every hour. I plan on running this in my command prompt perpetually, but am afraid that doing so could be detrimental in some way to my computer.

The script checks every second via `setInterval` to see if it is the top of the hour, so it is executing something every second. Here's what it sort of looks like:

```
var hourOfLastTweet;

function post() {
    //Post to the Twitter API...
}

setInterval(function () {
    var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    if (mins == "00" && hour != hourOfLastTweet) {
        hourOfLastTweet = hour;
        post();
    }
}, 1000);
```

I currently have my sleep settings set such that the monitor sleeps after five minutes and my computer never sleeps and the script is always running, making that check every second. If I were to run this for months on end, should I be at all concerned that it would damage my computer or have a negative impact on performance in any way?

Comment: You reinvented the wheel. This could be implemented much better. Have a look at ```cron``` and ```at```. However, it is unlikely to damage your HW.

Comment: I think I'm gonna write a batch file that is scheduled to run at the top of every hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers are designed to run continuously. There is no problem in doing that. Many companies use them like that, even more, now with the increased work-from-home options.

Further, from an electrical engineering perspective, most electrical parts designed for a computer will take more wear damage at power-on compared to heavy continuous use. That means your HDD is more likely to fail if you start and stop it each day for 1 year compared to letting it powered-on for the same full year.

From a programming perspective, there is no problem unless if your code has a bad design flaw that will make it use excessive RAM or other resources over time.

Comment: Thanks @Overmind. I figured this was the case, but am much more acquainted with writing code than understanding computer hardware. I may consider finding a way around the check that runs every second, maybe setting a timer for 3600 seconds after the first occurrence of `Date().getMinutes == ‘00’`, or listening for some notification, though I imagine this requires similar resources to continuously checking for some condition being true.

Comment: Resources for such a thing are very low, totally insignificant, even less than running an ICMP (ping) continuously.

Comment: @DavidChopin with the way you are considering to program it, it is likely that there is a moment where either the code runs twice, or not at all. Using a loop and just checking if the minutes is 0 is never a good idea. Very fault tolerant. It is far easier to use a scheduled task that runs your program every hour.